# How can I really call a shell command in my Perl script?

Tags: perl, tcsh

How to execute shell commands, retaining all ENV variables, specifying shell type/instance etc.
Having access to all aliases, and setting further aliases.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system("alias test-alias echo TEST;");
system("test-alias;");
system("echo \$SHELL");
```

Results in:

```
sh: line 0: alias: test-alias: not found
sh: line 0: alias: echo: not found
sh: line 0: alias: TEST: not found
sh: test-alias: command not found
/tool/pandora/bin/tcsh
```

Comment: Each `system` call spawns a new instance of the shell, so it will not remember any changes made in the previous shell. And the shell is `sh`, not `tcsh` like you tagged your question.

Comment: Though I have to say, storing ENV variables in the shell inside Perl is somewhat silly, since Perl can store the variables for you much more easily.

Comment: Like the error message says, `system` uses the system shell `sh`. It does not understand the syntax of commands written for the incompatible [tag:tcsh]. (Most people stopped using that shell some 30 years ago; probably you should, too.)

Comment: Need ENV variables as setup for further shell commands, the spawned shell is sh but returns $SHELL as tcsh, is that reasonable?

Comment: @TLP Is it possible to spawn a persistent shell to pass things to from Perl?

Comment: @Nibblerglozer I highly doubt it, because it is such a pointless thing to do. Why do you want to do that?¨

Comment: @Nibblerglozer Looks like you want to ... mix shell with Perl?  Run a shell script out of a Perl script in a sense? Or what -- can you state what the goal of this is?  That would help us help you out.  You could write a shell script (in a string) and run that via `system`, in a way that would allow the use of aliases and all, but why? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> alias: test-alias not found
> alias: echo not found
> alias: TEST not found
> ```

This is because the correct syntax for creating an alias in `sh` is

```bash
alias test-alias='echo TEST'
```

Fixed:

```perl
system("alias test-alias='echo TEST'");
```

---

> `sh: 1: test-alias: not found`

You still get this after fixing the first problem. You did create a shell, and you did create an alias named `test-alias` in it, but that shell exited. You are running `test-alias;` in a new shell, one in which `test-alias` hasn't been created.

You need to run both commands in the same shell.

Fixed:

```perl
system("alias test-alias='echo TEST'\ntest-alias");
```

Comment: This still won't work because aliases are not expanded in noninteractive shells. Even then, aliases are not expanded on the same command line where you defined them, at least in Bash.

Comment: @tripleee It does work: _existing_ aliases are not expanded (but one can make them with `shopt`), and the `\n` in there takes care of the other remark.  Try: `perl -we'system("alias tal=\"echo TEST\"\ntal")'`.

Comment: @tripleee, Re "*This still won't work because aliases are not expanded in noninteractive shells*", Not true. Aliases work in both interactive and non-interactive shells. That's why we normally make sure to only create them in interactive shell, cause overriding say `ls` could break scripts. Try it yourself: `perl -e'system("alias test-alias='\''echo TEST'\''\ntest-alias");'`

Comment: Re "*they seem to want their existing environment to work*", Nothing special about the shell created by Perl. It will run startup scripts as normal. And it passes on the env as normal. The OP even proved this by printing inherited env var SHELL. So the only question is how to setup further aliases. This question answers that.

Comment: @zdim, Whatcha talking about? Aliases work fine in non-interactive shells, and aliases in .tcshrc are picked up even in non-interactive shells. [Demo](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/0c4202683143ebddbeeb1321fd2a2afa)

Comment: @ikegami  It doesn't work in my test, as it doesn't load aliases defined in my `.tcshrc`, no matter what I try.  I posted an example with comments, as a comment to your `Demo` link, [here](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/0c4202683143ebddbeeb1321fd2a2afa).  Anyway, I didn't mean to distract from this answer so I cleaned up my comments (except for the first one)

Comment: @zdim, Works for me, as I showed. No idea what's wrong with yours. Or why you ran entirely different commands???

Comment: "_as I showed._"  -- you define that alias in the running shell so then it exists later; i don't see how that shows loading aliases from `.tcshrc` (but perhaps I'm missing something of course?).  I added commands to my example for debugging, since things weren't working (and they still don't).  Anyway -- I hate to bother anyone, you the least, with something what clearly isn't of interest (to me neither, was just curious).  So I suggest to remove all this (I'd just leave my first comment which refutes wrong critique of your answer)

Comment: @zdim, 3rd command creates an alias in .tcshrc. 4th command shows the alias being loaded from .tcshrc

Comment: OK ... why does the 4th command show the alias loaded from .tcshrc?  The 2nd command defined that alias in the running shell (so it is available even if it doesn't get loadaed)?

Comment: @zdim, Why do you think running `alias` in one process has any effect on unrelated processes??? Anyway, updated demo to be clearer

Comment: Alright, so that does clear it up -- the most bare-bones example doesn't work for me (I added a comment there).  Now this is curious...

Comment: "_Why do you think running `alias` in one process has any effect on unrelated processes_" --- didn't realize what was what in those examples...

Comment: So it is about the shell version (I comment there)! Thank you. Clean up here?

Answer (score 0):

Perl has the special global `%ENV` that stores all the Environment variables that Perl itself launched with. To get the `SHELL` environment variable you can just write.

```perl
my $shell = $ENV{SHELL};
```

To get all environment variable.

```perl
while ( my ($key,$value) = each %ENV ) {
    printf "%s => %s\n", $key, $value;
}
```

You also can use this hash to store new environment variables.

```perl
$ENV{FOO} = "bla";
system('echo $FOO');
```

The above will print `bla`. And sure if you do.

```perl
$ENV{FOO} = "bla";
system('/bin/bash');
```

Then it spawns a new Shell and you have `$FOO` set there. But I don't see a point here. Just use `.profile` in Linux or whatever to set environment variables.

The last bit seems to my like a classical XY Problem.